# Laravel5 on windows7 xampp

Tags: laravel

I installed laravel5 on windows successfully. but showing errors when i copy codes from [here](https://packagist.org/search/?tags=laravel) want to install any other dependencies?

i got something like this(screenshot). also it is keep saying to update loadash and graceful-fs.. How to do that?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoq3Z.png)

Comment: So it would help if you updated your question with the actual errors :)

Comment: You're using composer, right?  We need more details.

Comment: yes am using composer

Comment: @Ciccio . Can u pls check my screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a better command line tool then Command Prompt. Try installing [Git Bash](https://git-scm.com/downloads)

Once you've done this I would suggest going through the Laravel installation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/installation)

Comment: Thanks :)  I'll do it